# Get Base URL value from JS in adminhtml/frontend (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, javascript, frontend

I want to send AJAX request to the REST API on server from popup in adminhtml and I need "Base URL" value to construct complete URL. I see the following code on the HTML page:

```
<html><head>
    <script>
        var BASE_URL = 'http://host.com/admin/catalog/';
        var FORM_KEY = 'aAopAjLMymxMN17J';
        var require = {
            "baseUrl": "http://host.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US"
        };
    </script>
</head></html>
```

I can remove `/admin/catalog/` from global `BASE_URL` and get the target value, but is there a better way to get Base URL value in JS in adminhtml?

This global variable does not present on the frontend:

```
<html><head>
    <script>
        var require = {
            "baseUrl": "http://host.com/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_EN"
        };
    </script>
</head></html>
```

Does exist a method to get Base URL value in JS that is common for both adminhtml & frontend?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code line in your block:

- You should try `$block->getBaseUrl()`.
- Get base url admin : `$block->getUrl('adminhtml')` => `http://host.com/admin`

Comment: I have no server side PHP block. All I have are: (1) JS module (./Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/...) and (2) HTML template that is loaded by this JS module (./Vendor/Module/view/base/web/template/...). This code is embedded into adminhtml page as ui-component (xml file in ./Vendor/Module/adminhtml/ui_component/)

Comment: In your Ui component, there are Url actions? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139424/how-to-create-action-buttons-in-magento2-grid/

Comment: Yes, I have an actions links in the grid:

 <listing>
  <columns>
   <actionsColumn name="..." class="...">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/actions</item>
     </item>
    </argument>
   </actionsColumn>
  </columns>
 </listing>